# PS4 double nat issue

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have an app that i want to access remotely my ps4. i have made a port forward, and everything is working fine, but when i want to go further it shows me an error like i had a Double Nat configured on my network, and i don't have. The cable from ISP is coming directly in my router, and i'm using pppoe conection. I don't have a static IP , if that matters.i have tried to disable dhcp, and assign manualy am ip for each device, but when i hit submit, the router swith to aumatomaticaly dhcp server.

Comment: DHCP = auto assigned IP addresses, it has nothing to do with NAT (network address translation). Check the IP that's assigned to the wan interface of the router, make sure it doesn't start with "192.168", "172.16" or "10.10". Write down the IP you get from the routers web-gui, go to canyouseeme.org, compare the addresses. Are they the same or different?

Comment: are not the same, i don't know why

Comment: What are the first two octets? It sounds to me like you do not have a public wan address. I.E you are behind carrier grade NAT

Comment: in the wan interface of the router the ip begin with 100.112...., and the ip from canyouseeme.org begin with 82.77...

Comment: What specific error is it?

Comment: failed to configure for internet play as a Double Nat configuration was detected on your network. error code 20004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, you are behind Carrier grade NAT. This is confirmed by the WAN address being different from the publically seen address. You can ask your ISP to assign you a public IP, my guess is it will cost more than your current ISP plan. They may not have additional free public IP addresses though.

But it's definitely worth a shot!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. now i understand why i have this issue.